# RxJS cancellable HTTP queue

Tags: angular, rxjs, queue, observable

I'm trying to implement some sort of queueing with support for cancelling (or not) an ongoing HTTP request.

In my head, it looks something like this, but I can't seem to find the "propper tools" for the job :/

1. Click Load More for **Item A**
2. Send Http Request for **Item A**
3. Click Load More for **Item B**
4. Send Http Request for **Item B**
5. Click (again) Load More for **Item B** (while the previous Request was still ongoing)
6. Should cancel previous Request for **Item B**
7. Should Send Http Request for (the new) **Item B**
8. Click Load More for Item A (currently an ongoing Request for **Item B** is active)
9. It, doesn't matter: Send Http Request for **Item A**

My first idea was to use a **takeUntil** together with the **concatMap** and somehow cancel the ongoing request. But then, how can I actually check the items of the queue? It feels like I'm missing a handy operator.

```
// in the service
queue.pipe(
 tap(()=> {  how to check and trigger sameItem$.next() })
 // using concatMap to process every item from the queue sequentially
 concatMap((item) => this.httpClient.get(item)).pipe(takeUntil(this.sameItem$))
).subscribe((x)=> {console.log('response', x)})


// In the component
loadMore(item){
this.queueService.queue.next(item);
}
```

I was also thinking about using **switchMap** or **concatMap** based on "is the item already in the queue?" but I don't even know if this makes any sense :)

Also don't mind if the solution goes on a different direction, as long as I can leverage the power of RxJS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have some kind of `id` in the item, you could do something like this.

```
queue.pipe(
    groupBy((item) => item.id), // split queue values into independent obs based on grouping key
    mergeMap( // process each group obs in parallel
      (group$) => group$.pipe(
        switchMap((item) => this.httpClient.get(item)) //cancel prev req in the group if still running
      )
    )
  )
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

cheers